# How to take database backup and restore? And how can I view it?

Tags: mysql

I am using this commands to  backup and restore my database

```
mysqldump -u transgenic -p[ramesh] [transgenic] > transgenic.sql
mysql -u transgenic -p[ramesh] [transgenic] < transgenic.sql
```

I am trying this after opening my terminal and I tried again opening my mysql also but I'm not able to see my restored one. How could I know previous one and restored one?

Answer (score 0):

To restore from backup, login to mysql 
and

```
mysql> source transgenic.sql
```